# How to customize the Places Bar with Quick Access for Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

So I've already found how to customize the Places Bar in the Common File Dialog for Windows 7-8 (see here: http://www.howtogeek.com/97824/how-to-customize-the-file-opensave-dialog-box-in-windows/)

But what I'd like to do is to customize the places and *still* have the Quick Access place in Windows 10. I cannot find how to add the Quick Access folder using the existing methods for Windows 7/8.

Comment: You can't. [Add items to your favorites](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/10357/add-your-own-folders-to-favorites-in-windows-7/) in Quick Access and/or edit the places bar as shown in that tutorial. You can't combine both. Because [as said in the tutorial](https://i.imgur.com/dYetPZP.png), it's two different types of save dialog boxes

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean: it is indeed possible to customize the Places Bar, as described in the link I posted.

My question isn't about how to add things in Quick Access, or how to customize Places Bar in general, but how to add Quick Access into Places Bar when customizing it.

To clarify: by default, Quick Access is the first item on Places Bar in WIn10. But when you customize Places Bar, there doesn't seem to be a way to add Quick Access as one of the Places. This is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You can't. They are two different types of dialogs boxes. [Look here on my PC](http://i.imgur.com/S1YCUlI.png). What I'm saying is if you customize the Places Bar you can't add Quick Access in addition.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still not sure if we're on the same page. The dialog box I'm talking about is the one on the right in your picture; I'm not concerned with the dialog box on the left at all. Did you take that screenshot in Win10? In my Win10, the default Places are Quick Access, Desktop, Libraries, Computer, Network. I know I can customize this dialog box, I just can't add Quick Access once I customize it. Sorry for the back and forth, but I just want to make sure we're talking about the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to get the entire "Quick Access" dialogue in the customized Places, but I was able to add the "Frequent folders" portion by setting one of the "Places" string values to the following:

```
shell:::{3936E9E4-D92C-4EEE-A85A-BC16D5EA0819}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but just in case anybody else is trying to solve this one...

These instructions for customizing the Windows 10 32-bit common dialog places bar outline the basic procedure of adding your own places via registry edits:
https://www.howtogeek.com/97824/how-to-customize-the-file-opensave-dialog-box-in-windows/

But nothing here refers to Quick Access and there's no DWORD code for it I could find.

I created a shortcut to Quick Access on the desktop by dragging it from File Explorer. Looking at the shortcut in a hex editor gave me this value:

```
{d34a6ca6-62c2-4c34-8a7c-14709c1ad938}
```

I tried using the "shell:::" trick with this value, but it didn't add Quick Access.

What did work was the "godmode" hack -

1 . Create a folder in my profile folder and name it `"QuickAccess.{d34a6ca6-62c2-4c34-8a7c-14709c1ad938}"` (The QuickAccess part doesn't matter - just a placeholder.) When you open this folder, it takes you to Quick Access.

2. In the registry at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\comdlg32\Placesbar` create a string value like "Place0" with a value of `"c:\users\MyUserName\QuickAccess.{d34a6ca6-62c2-4c34-8a7c-14709c1ad938}"`

This added the Quick Access folder & icon to the places bar!

Both steps may not be needed - maybe step 2 will work by itself? YMMV.